# Creating a favicon

Tags: html, favicon

How can I create and use a favicon for my website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)

Comment: @Gothdo This is not a duplicate! The one you point to IS! This one preceded that one by a year and a half!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming but web design.

Comment: @DovMiller The better question with the better answers is the one that should remain open.

Answer (score 109):

I stoped working on the site and it's now disabled. There are other similar solutions, like https://realfavicongenerator.net

---

Searching about favicons, I discovered I needed more than 10 kinds of files to work in all browsers and devices :(

I got pissed and created my own favicon generator, that creates all these files and the correct HTML header for each one of them: [faviconit.com](http://faviconit.com)

Hope you enjoy it.

Comment: Excellent app. This is one of the best favicon generator sites I've seen.

Comment: @EduardoRusso this is simply awesome - thanks!

Comment: Good job. Works as expected.

Comment: Works better than expected!  Tiny bug(?): when using advanced, the path and version are not included in the browserconfig.xml. Still love it, though. :D

Comment: This is fantastic. Much more than I expected.

Comment: Thank you i bookmark it. Also you can check https://fav-icon.com and you can create 16x16 , 24x24 or 48x48 dimensions of favicon.

Comment: I am unable to get to the website, it says the browser can't connect to the server at faviconit.com `:/`

Comment: Hi @Wimateeka, I'm sorry but the site was not having enough access and I ended up disabling it

Answer (score 44):

If you already have a logo image that you want to transform into a favicon, then you can convert it using http://www.favicomatic.com/. 
It creates crisp favicons, and I haven't had to edit them after creating them.
It will generate favicons at 16x16 and 32x32 and to quote them: "Every damn size, sir!". The site also supports/preserves transparency present in some pngs.
Also, their site looks cool and is easy to use.

For example here is a stackoverflow logo:
[image]

Here are some of the generated favicons:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

They also generate the needed html:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" href="apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128" />
<meta name="application-name" content="&nbsp;"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile-144x144.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="mstile-70x70.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="mstile-150x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="mstile-310x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="mstile-310x310.png" />
```

I looked at the first 20 or so google results, and this was by far the best.

Comment: How can I improve this answer to avoid further downvotes?

Comment: I don't know. Your answer made this a five minute job for me. Thanks.

Comment: some people just like to downvote for no reason. SO needs to have policy against it. Btw, do we really need many different size or we 16x16 and 32x32 are just enough as website generates

Comment: I personally don't know what the best practice is here. On my site I think we just use one. These could be helpful for chrome progressive web apps when combined with a manifest.json.

Comment: I found this resource on http://www.favicomatic.com/, it's called the "Favicon Cheat Sheet" https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet

Comment: This website still works! (I couldn't reach the website in the answer above this one)

Answer (score 20):

[GIMP](http://gimp.org) is a good program for that. Just save the image as PNG, then add

```
 <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/favicon.png">
```

on the `<HEAD>`section of your page.

Comment: Gimp also offers the option of saving it as favicon.ico, which would save the trouble of adding the link.

Comment: Pity that the old MSIEs (that are still quite popular) won't accept the PNG in place of a "proper" ICO formatted file.

Comment: To pin websites to the taskbar, Windows requires an ico too.

Answer (score 9):

You create a icon file that's 16x16 or 32x32 or 64x64.  Name it favicon.ico and place it in the root of your website public folder.

There are websites that will convert other graphic formats to .ico for you.  ie. http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/

Comment: *Also:* you can save your favicon file anywhere if you add a `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="link/to/fav.ico" />` to the `<head>` block of your pages.

Comment: tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon will also allow you to merge multiple size in one favico which is great

Answer (score 5):

One of the best online favicon tools is [FaviconGenerator.com](http://www.favicongenerator.com).  Fast, modern design, no fluff.

Comment: [FaviconGenerator.com](http://www.favicongenerator.com/) also provides access to their API from node/grunt/gulp.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create .ico files, you can also use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) to create favicons.  Modern browsers can use normal image files, but originally I think it was just .ico files.  It's an open source image editor similar to Photoshop.  Create and edit an image of the right size (say 32 x 32), flatten to one layer (Unless you want multiple icons in the same file), and save as a .ico.  It'll format it correctly, then use Stefano's `<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/favicon.ico">` to use it in your webpage.

Answer (score 3):

I use the open source [Paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/) program along with the [Icon plugin](http://paint.net.amihotornot.com.au/features/effects/plugins/file_types/Ico_Cur/).

You can then create and save an image in the .ico format with all the different sizes embedded into the .ico file.

Comment: Hmm, paint.net.amihotornot.com.au as the host for the Icon plugin? Is that legit?

Comment: @RonaldB yes it's the home of that plugin. Weird domain isn't it

Answer (score 3):

When creating a favicon, you want to take the following factors into account:

- **Supported platforms** Ten years ago, you only wanted to support desktop browsers and the solution was to generate the classic `favicon.ico` picture. Nowadays, you want to support iOS (and iOS Safari) and Android (and Android Chrome). Maybe Windows 10 (and Edge) and the new Mac Book Pro Touch Bar, too (macOS Safari). You cannot just use a single "one size fits all" image anymore.
- **Design** As soon as you support multiple platforms, you are facing multiple design guidelines. For example, Google is using transparent icons for its own native apps on Android, while iOS icons cannot be transparent at all. You cannot just use a "single design fits all" approach.
- **Generated icons and HTML code** For two or three years, the reference has been to generate as many icons as possible in order to cover all cases. I am afraid I created this trend all by myself :-/ The problem is that you end up with 20-something lines or HTML, which is way too much. In order to have a satisfying technical solution, you need to balance the amount of generated icons/HTML and the supported platforms.

As usual, you can create all these assets manually. Unless you have very, very specific needs and a budget, this is definitely not the way to go.

The right way for most people is to use a favicon generator that lets you decide of the look of all the icons and takes care of all the details. The only one which does this is [Real Favicon Generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). Full disclosure: I am the author of this site.

Answer (score 2):

I make my favicons either 16 x 16 or 32 x 32 using Photoshop. I save it as gif then and I use [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.de/) to convert the gif to an ico.

Answer (score 1):

And if you are using asp.net try this way to apply favicon to your page :

```
<link runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link runat="server" rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

but you can find more information here : http://doctype.com/

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).