# How to change the icon on the image

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a favicon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547150/how-to-create-a-favicon)

How to set the [encircled icon](http://esbhive.appspot.com/file/images/forum.jpg) of my website? (I don't have enough reputation to post images here.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547150/how-to-create-a-favicon

Comment: @zerocrates I didn't know the name "favicon"

Answer (score 3):

Look up favicon

Here is what I put in the HEAD section of my HTML pages

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"  />

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icons/iphone57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/icons/iphone72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/icons/iphone114.png" />
```

The apple icons will also set the icon for iPhone and iPad.
Your favicon file should be 32x32 or 64x64.

Answer (score 1):

As Daveo said.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

It is a 16x16 pixel image, put it on your webroot. ie htdocs on apache.

Rename the picture to favicon.ico

It shall be automatically pick up by webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Visit dynamic drive for a great favicon generator...

[Favicon generator](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon)