# How to force favicon to appear

Tags: php, favicon

Okay, so I've tried every variation of the link rel code, including the -moz and - webkit ones, that I could find. No luck so far, and I've come to the conclusion that it might be my host blocking automatic client-side downloads, which is in the terms of service. So, I was wondering if I could make a PHP script that forces it to display server-side. I'm hoping for something simple like

```
<php>
$favicon= ("/favicon.ico");
?>
```

Of course that's pseudocode and there are syntax errors, but what would I actually write to do this?

Comment: Have you tried making a `favicon.ico` in your server's document root? (Aka the folder that corresponds to the root of your website). Try clearing your browser cache. Also, php code opens with `<?php`

Comment: How would you display something serverside? The link rel code is supposed to work, make sure you're giving the right link to the favicon img.

Comment: It's in my root, but I went into the code and noticed I have like 10 of them. One for Firefox bookmarks, one for chrome bookmarks, and a bunch of different apple and android devices. All of them seem to work except the one that displays the favicon in the browser. It works just fine on my file:// copy, but not online

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a favicon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547150/creating-a-favicon)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Echo this in your head section of your page

```
<head>
  <?php 
      echo '<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />'; 
  ?>
</head>
```

Comment: why open PHP with `<?php` if all you want to do is echo a constant string?

Comment: idk, OP was trying to use php so I gave a solution with php. Maybe he wants to make the favicon dynamic?

Comment: you have a syntax error in your html code at `.ico"); ">`

Answer (score 1):

You either need to put your `favicon.ico` file in the root directory of your website, or you can use HTML to point the browser to it:

`<link rel="icon" href="/foo/bar/favicon.ico"/>`