# How to change the logo in the URL of a liferay portal?

Tags: liferay

I want to change this liferay logo to one of my own. How do i do it? I do not want to create a new theme, but make changes in the existing WELCOME theme of liferay.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a favicon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547150/creating-a-favicon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put your custom `favicon.ico` file in the `docroot/_diffs/images` folder of your theme, if you are working on one.

If you’re not then create one using `classic` as the *parent theme* so you don’t need to customize it in any way to have the standard look and feel.

Comment: Did you try to hit refresh or clean the cache in the affected browsers? In which browser did it not work?

Comment: It did not work on IE and Firefox. I tested it in Chrome, its working fine.

Comment: As you said, i cleared the cache of both IE and FF, now its working on FF ,but not on IE.

Comment: IE has even a more aggressive cacheing for favicons. If you want to see if it’s working or not, access your portal through a different domain/ip.

For example, if you’re developing on `localhost:8080` try `127.0.0.1:8080`.