# What is favicon.ico?

Tags: html, flask, web, react-fullstack

I am a new user to python flask and when I run my flask website on VS Code terminal i found that it is showing me that "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
I want to know what does it mean and why is it showing me the 404 error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547150/creating-a-favicon)

Answer (score 7):

It isn't required. It stands for "favourite icon" and is the icon the browser will use when displaying the page. You know the logos in each tab of a web browser? Those are favicons.

Answer (score 6):

A favicon is an icon that appears at the top of a browser tab. Although they are not required, favicons are important because they help the user identify your site. If you would like to generate a favicon, use this link [Favicon Generator](https://www.favicon-generator.org)
Add this code to the  section of your website`<link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >`